# android sqlite db onUpgrade failed the sql executed but no change

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to upgrade my database of android, the new version is 2, and the onUpgrade() of SQLiteOpenHelper called in my app. But it seems that the db has no change. My operation remove a column and add a new column for the Student table.

Before the upgrade, the student has (_phone,_name,_id,_age) four columns;

After the upgrade, excepted student has (_phone,_name,_id,_address) for columns (remove _age and add _address column);

But I failed, the final result is the student struct not changed.

```
    String createTempTable = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE student_temp_1(_phone TEXT,_name TEXT,_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);";
    String insertTempTable = "INSERT INTO student_temp_1 SELECT _phone,_name,_id FROM student;";
    String dropTable = "DROP TABLE  student";

    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE student (_address TEXT,_phone TEXT,_name TEXT,_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);";
    String insertTable = "INSERT INTO student(_phone,_name,_id) SELECT _phone,_name,_id FROM student_temp_1;";
    String dropTempTable = "DROP TABLE student_temp_1;";
    db.beginTransaction();
    db.execSQL(createTempTable);
    db.execSQL(insertTempTable);
    db.execSQL(dropTable);
    db.endTransaction();
    // here I execute the PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(student); it returned empty. so the sql is executed.
    db.beginTransaction();
    db.execSQL(createTable);
    db.execSQL(insertTable);
    db.execSQL(dropTempTable);
    db.endTransaction();
```

Comment: Hi Jamling Li,could you show us the ```onUpdate()``` method?

Comment: using `beginTransaction(); ...... endTransaction();` will effectively do nothing. You need to code **`setTransactionSuccessful()`** to signify that the transactions should be committed (i.e. the changes are OK) before the `endTransaction();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `beginTransaction` .... `endTransaction` without a **`setTransactionSuccessful`** (*before the `endTransaction` and after the `beginTransaction`*) will not commit the changes and thus do nothing of value.

As such you should implement the use of **`setTransactionSuccessful`** e.g. change your code to :-

```
    db.beginTransaction();
    db.execSQL(createTempTable);
    db.execSQL(insertTempTable);
    db.execSQL(dropTable);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<
    db.endTransaction();
    // here I execute the PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(student); it returned empty. so the sql is executed.
    db.beginTransaction();
    db.execSQL(createTable);
    db.execSQL(insertTable);
    db.execSQL(dropTempTable);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<
    db.endTransaction();
```

As you experienced e.g. the comments

> // here I execute the PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(student); it returned empty.
>   so the sql is executed.

and

> After the upgrade, excepted student has (_phone,_name,_id,_address)
>   for columns (remove _age and add _address column);

Although confusing, although hopefully not now, this shows that your code worked in principle (*i.e. the `dropTable` did appear to drop the table (however that got undone due to the `endTransaction` without the `setTransactionSuccessful`)*). As such, you could conclude, that you only actually need a single transaction, so your code could be :-

```
    db.beginTransaction();
    db.execSQL(createTempTable);
    db.execSQL(insertTempTable);
    db.execSQL(dropTable);
    db.execSQL(createTable);
    db.execSQL(insertTable);
    db.execSQL(dropTempTable);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
```

Saying that I would personally introduce some checks before dropping the original table, so a rename of the original table instead of the drop with a drop after checking (*e.g. row counts of new against row count of original and column count of temp against against column count of new*).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I think you wan't to delete the one column and keep all other information. I would recommend to you to use ALTER TABLE.

```
ALTER TABLE student  DROP COLUMN _age, ADD _address TEXT;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The alter table can't remove column, so I created a temp table to store the kept data

Comment: Really? I have to try this again when I'm home. Can't really believe that it can't remove columns. It's in the MySQL and SQL reference manual so it should work.

Comment: here is the link of [ALTER_TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) I'll try the official suggestion to upgrade again.

Comment: @CodeRed ***The only schema altering commands directly supported by SQLite are the "rename table" and "add column" commands shown above.*** [ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

Comment: Interesting. Well I always did research on the mysql and sql manuals and never had problems. But that's really good to know.